# Difference between "I failed' x "I've failed"

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I saw two episodes from different series and one of them says: `I failed` and the other says `I've failed at that`.

I know which senteces shown represents `Simple Past` and `Present Perfect` but I still do not understand the difference between the sentences.

Comment: "I've failed at all" sounds weird to me, maybe it's a British thing? On the contrary "I haven't failed at all" sounds good, and it doesn't mean the negation of "I've failed at everything". What series was it? I admit, though, this is a tough one, it's a bit like the difference between the imparfait and the passé composé in French. I never figured out a system for which one is right, you just get used to them in certain contexts.

Comment: Yeah man, I agree with you. This `I have failed at all`  was said by James Spader on Blacklist episode

Comment: @ThMoraes I got curious. Which season/episode of *The Blacklist* was it?

Comment: @JustinYoung S03E05

Comment: @ThMoraes If it's the episode S3E5 "Arioch Cain", there is only one *failed* in the episode. What he said was "Well, I failed at that." (rather than "at all"). (I asked about it because I shared the same feeling with Justin Young. "I've failed at all." also sounded weird to me.)

Comment: Sorry about that, It was my mistake. He really says `at that`, actually I fixed it in my question, I heard his saying `I have failed` and immediatly after I put the subtitles to confirm that, but What did sounds weird? The fact of using `Present Perfect` or my grammar mistake?

Comment: It's the "at all", "I've failed at that" or "I failed at that" both sound fine, with slightly different meanings (see below).

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing, but until now I'm waiting someone answer my comments there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**past simple** is used for an event or action that happened in a specific point in the past. The past events have no connection with the present.

> I failed at maths yesterday. - Why? - I didn't study enough.

**present perfect** is used for an event or action that happened at any time in the past. The exact time isn't important. The events have connection with the present.

> I've failed at maths. I'm not going anywhere this weekend.

Comment: +1 But in the past-tense version there is obviously *some* connection with the present, or the speaker wouldn't say it. It might more accurately be said that the sentence does not refer to any present relevance.

Comment: Exactly, **relevance**.

Comment: Sorry but I still do not understand what will be the difference between these sentences. Well, but when you failed in something, you failed in a specific point in the past, right? Or you mean, when he failed in something and it brought consequences to the present, we must use Present perfect, because it has connection with the present?

Comment: Both contexts makes me think in which the two sentences, both characters made mistakes in the past and today these "mistakes" still bothering them. But one of them apply correct grammar

Comment: Try this one: "I was there" vs "I have been there". Say you're being questioned by the police on your whereabouts on a particular night, and they ask you if you were at such-and-such address on the night in question. If you say "I was there", it means yes, you were there that night. If you say "I have been there", it means you were there at some undefined point in the past, but not necessarily the night in question.

Answer (score 0):

( I failed) = simple past tense : we use this tense to say about a activitie that was happened in past.

( I have failed ) = present perfect : we use this tense to say about just now  happened actions

Comment: I am afraid your second sentence is not true. If someone asks me which countries I have been to in South America I can reply "I have been to Brazil" even though it was more than twenty years ago.